# Error al implementar los queryMethods, query JPA y query native

Tags: spring-boot, spring, jpa, spring-data

Espero me puedas ayudar.

Estoy usando JPA para la persistencia, y el problema radica en que cuando uso los métodos de la interfaces funciona correctamente y me trae data, pero cuando quiero implementar un método[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] personalizado y lo ejecuto no me saca error pero tampoco me trae información. HE intentado implementar las 3 formas, queryMethods, querys y query native. no se que puedo estar fallando.

Nota: con el método findAll me trae Data (información)
con los demás métodos no me trae nada y tampoco me arroja error.
Ya probé las query en la base de datos y funciona, he cambiado el tipo de dato pero nada

Adjunto imagen de la implementación.

Comment: no pongas el codigo como imagen no todos pueden verlo o dedicarse el tiempo a transcribirlo

Comment: prueba con un gestor de BD hacer la query a ver si rula o no

Answer (score 1):

Los métodos de CrudRepository no devuelven List, para eso tienes que extender de JpaRepository, esta interfaz si que sus métodos devuelve List.

Algunos métodos de CrudRepository
[image: Algunos métodos de CrudRepository:]

Algunos métodos de JpaRepository
[image: Algunos métodos de JpaRepository]

Te recomiendo echarle un vistazo a la documentación oficial de Spring sobre JpaRepository, ya que a los programadores nos es super útil para no tener que estar trabajando con Hibernate o directamente con el JDBC, Spring nos proporciona estas clases.
[Documentación oficial](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html)